# CreateFile() succeeds but the file is not on the disk.

Tags: c, createfile

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(LPCTSTR("filename"),          // name of the write
                          GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing and reading 
                          0,                                     // do not share
                          NULL,                                  // default security
                          OPEN_ALWAYS,                           // create new file only
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,                 // normal file
                          NULL); 
if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
            printf("Success.\n");
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

The operation succeeds but i can't find 'filename' on the disk.
Does CreateFile() actually creates file on the disk?

Comment: Look within your process current directory :) the file will be there

Comment: @ShmilTheCat - Nope. It's not there :)

Comment: ...or in any other directory that you cwd()'ed

Comment: looked all over the hard drive. can't see it

Comment: maybe your operation system does not create empty files? you could try to put an fwrite() before closing

Comment: @PeterMiehle - Actually this is my question :) If CreateFile itself creates the file on the disk (before writing)?

Comment: @PeterMiehl - I tried to write some data to the file - and still cant see it.

Comment: Try adding a path in front of the filename eg. `c:\filename`. This will help in finding it. Printing out GetLastError after CreateFile can help pin pointing problems. The path used can be relative to the compiler if you are running from within an environment

Answer (score 1):

I tried a minimal program containing only your code and ... the file was correctly created in current directory ! But only if the program is compiled in ANSI mode, because the LPCTSTR only converts the pointer to be a LPCTSTR but does not convert from ANSI to UNICODE. Only the `_T` macro does that.

You should use `GetCurrentDirectory` to control where you try to write the file, and use TCHAR to be UNICODE compatible :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    LPTSTR dir;
    DWORD cr = ::GetCurrentDirectory(0, NULL);
    cr += 1;
    dir = (LPTSTR) malloc(cr * sizeof(TCHAR));
    cr = ::GetCurrentDirectory(cr, dir);

    /* ::MessageBox(NULL, dir, _T("Current dir"), MB_OK); */
    _tprintf(_T("Current dir : %s\n"), dir); // note the _tprintf and _T macro
    free(dir);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_T("filename"),          // name of the write - _T
                          GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing and reading 
                          0,                                     // do not share
                          NULL,                                  // default security
                          OPEN_ALWAYS,                           // create new file only
                          FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,                 // normal file
                          NULL); 
if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
            printf("Success.\n");
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
return 0;
}
```

If I compile in UNICODE mode without the `_T` macro around `"filename"`, the program does create a file, but its name is simply garbage

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information, but here is a blind guess : your file is redirected to the VirtualStore.

Some locations, like "Program Files", are protected on the latest versions of Windows.
If your program is in a protected location and is not run as administrator, the read/write operations will be redirected to C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\MYFOLDER.
Running your program as admin should correct this wherever it is located.